# Can any one please suggest what's needed to change so that it becomes compatible with IPV6 also. Its working fine for IPV4

Tags: sockets, ipv6

```
int lookup_numeric( const char * hostname, char * ip_address )
{
    int index = 0;
    int value = 0;

    for( const char * cursor = hostname; ; ++cursor )
    {
    if( ( '0' <= *cursor ) && ( *cursor <= '9' ) )
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += *cursor - '0';
        if( value > 255 )
        break;
    }
    else if( *cursor == '.' )
    {
        if( index >= IpAddressSize ) //IpAddressSize is 16 for IPV6 and 4 for IPV4.
        break;
        ip_address[ index++ ] = (char)value;
        value = 0;
    }
    else if( *cursor == '\0' )
    {
        if( index != IpAddressSize - 1 )
        break;
        ip_address[ index ] = (char)value;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If 'it's working fine' for IPv4 then surely you must know what it does. If you don't know what it does, how can you know that 'it's working fine'?

Comment: @Len ...actually its taking the address say "127.0.0.1" and filling it in ip_address array. But how should I acheive this for IPV6 ? This is my doubt

Comment: I would suggest that you change the title of the question then...

Comment: So basically [`inet_pton`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function appears to take a text representation of an IPv4 address (e.g. "127.0.0.1") and converts it into an array of bytes.

You really shouldn't be doing this kind of thing by hand, in my opinion, you'd be better off using [getaddrinfo()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo) which is probably available on your platform.

Comment: Couldn’t agree more. O.P. is just reinventing the wheel. A clever programmer may be intelligent enough to write some code like the above. But a smart programmer will know there is already a standard function to do the job.